# Stuck at "Installing update..." in recovery mode

Tags: cyanogenmod, updates, nexus-4, boot-loop, 4.4-kitkat

I am not able to flash my Nexus 4 with Cyanogenmod 11 anymore. The installation does not successfully finish, which is probably why it gets stuck in a boot loop after restarting the phone.

During the initial installation by sideloading the Cyanogenmod 11 zip, the process stops at the step **Installing update..**

It never says update finished. So I just restarted the phone manually afterwards. But it does not boot Cyanogenmod successfully.

The phone either...

- ...gets stuck at the Cyanogenmod boot splash indefinetely
- ...gets stuck at the window **Android is upgrading.. / Starting apps.**

I have formatted the following partitions beforehand to perform a  clean install: /system, /cache, /data, /persist, /firmware

Comment: When it gets stuck at boot splash, does the cyanogenmod logo appears, so is just blank?

Comment: @AnoopKP The cyanogenmod logo appears 100% working. The blue arrow keeps spinning indefinitely.

Comment: How did you did you flash CM? Did you use CWM? If yes, what version?

Comment: Did you verify the MD5 sum of the ROM first? It could be a corrupted / incomplete zip file. What recovery are you using? I would do a full wipe of all partitions again, redownload the firmware and try it again. Also I would get another ROM to try (even if you don't intend to use it). Can you restore a nandroid even? Also, ensure you are flashing the correct ROM for your version and that you are flashing the correct gapps! (I've been here a few times before!)

Comment: @geffchang I flashed CM by manually by entering recovery mode, wiping partitions and sideloading the installer zip.

Comment: @RossC I did verify the MD5 sum of the download. It matched up. I have tried both the latest nightly rom and older stable roms that have worked before.

Comment: Thanks for trying to help guys, I managed to flash the latest CM11 nightly after first doing a clean install of the 4.4.2 Google Stock Android.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had suspected that formatting additional partitions like `/firmware` and `/persist` might be somehow related my boot loop - but I have no educated confirmation of this! Any CM aftermarket firmware that I tried would get stuck at the boot though.

The following solved my problem:

1. [Install the (latest) Google Stock Android](https://developers.google.com/android/nexus/images?hl=de#instructions) - this is just as easy as installing Cyanogenmod
2. [Install ClockworkMod Recovery](http://wiki.cyanogenmod.org/w/Install_CM_for_mako#Installing_recovery_using_fastboot)
3. [Install Cyanogenmod Rom](http://wiki.cyanogenmod.org/w/Install_CM_for_mako)